"Flask-SocketIO with Eventlet: 'The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols' Error"
I'm trying to set up a WebSocket connection using Flask-SocketIO with Eventlet, but I'm encountering the error: "The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols." I've ensured that both the server and client are using compatible versions, but the issue persists.
Server-Side Setup:
I have the following versions installed:
pip install flask-socketio==5.3.2
pip install python-socketio==5.3.0
pip install python-engineio==4.3.1
pip install eventlet

Here is my server code (app.py):
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
import eventlet

# Use eventlet for async I/O
eventlet.monkey_patch()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet', cors_allowed_origins='*')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(msg):
    print('Message received: ' + msg)
    send('Message received: ' + msg)

@socketio.on('custom_event')
def handle_custom_event(json):
    print('Received json: ' + str(json))
    emit('response', {'data': 'Custom event response'})

# This is the WSGI entry point for cPanel
def application(environ, start_response):
    return socketio.server.handle_request(environ, start_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)


Client-Side Setup:
I'm using the following client-side code (templates/index.html):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask-SocketIO with Eventlet</title>
    <!-- Use a compatible version of Socket.IO -->
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.3.2/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            var socket = io();

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.send('User has connected!');
            });

            socket.on('message', function(data) {
                console.log('Message from server: ' + data);
            });

            socket.on('response', function(data) {
                console.log('Custom event response: ' + data.data);
            });

            function sendMessage() {
                socket.send('Hello from client!');
            }

            function sendCustomEvent() {
                socket.emit('custom_event', {data: 'Client sent custom event'});
            }

            window.sendMessage = sendMessage;
            window.sendCustomEvent = sendCustomEvent;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask-SocketIO with Eventlet</h1>
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
    <button onclick="sendCustomEvent()">Send Custom Event</button>
</body>
</html>


